# Too long execution time for update query

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm trying to update the table with a query, that executing in ~5 sec on Postgresql and Oracle but takes too long on Firebird 2.5.

```
UPDATE GoodsCatUnit SET isDisplay=1 
WHERE Id In (SELECT Min(gcu.Id) FROM GoodsCatUnit gcu GROUP BY gcu.GoodsCat_Id);
```

In the `GoodsCatUnit` ~34k rows and updating first 200 takes 15 seconds.

Comment: What is the plan output for this query. What is the DDL of the table, its constraints and its indexes? Have you tried making it a correlated update query instead of using `IN`?

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel correlated update query works well, thx: `UPDATE GoodsCatUnit gcu SET isDisplay=1
 WHERE gcu.id =(SELECT Min(gcu2.Id) FROM GoodsCatUnit gcu2 where gcu2.GoodsCat_Id = gcu.GoodsCat_Id GROUP BY gcu2.GoodsCat_Id);`

Comment: maybe apply index and instead of aggregate function, try `select top 1 gcu.id from goodscatunit gcu group by gcu.GoodsCat_Id order by gcu.id asc`

Comment: 1. Show the `plan` of the query. Chances are, you lack indexes on key fields or something.  2. Notice that when Firebird updates a field in a row - because of multi-version architecture (wikipedia -> MGA) it has to create a pre-update copy of the whole row (more or less), to introduce blocking of concurrent changes, if nothing more. So, I suggest adding condition `WHERE isDisplay <> 1` to reduce the number of updated=copied rows. 3. `IN` does not works nice when having many targets. Consider using `MERGE` command for such cases.

Comment: Also `SELECT Min(gcu.Id) FROM GoodsCatUnit gcu GROUP BY gcu.GoodsCat_Id` - would this query even get executed in modern SQL servers, having a group-column neither in `where` clause nor in `select` list ?

Answer (score 1):

Try writing this using a correlated subquery and defining an index.

The query is:

```
UPDATE GoodsCatUnit gcu
    SET isDisplay = 1 
    WHERE gcu.id = (SELECT MIN(gcu2.id) 
                    FROM GoodsCatUnit gcu2
                    WHERE gcu2.GoodsCat_Id = gcu.GoodsCat_Id
                   ) AND
          gcu.isDisplay <> 1;
```

The index is on `GoodsCatUnit(GoodsCat_Id, id)`.

Comment: I suggest adding condition `WHERE isDisplay <> 1` to reduce the number of updated=copied rows